# Why my editor doesnt work with theme of my web page?

Tags: java, jsp

Why my editor does not work with bootstrap style from my website (editor destroys my web page theme). I think there is a problem in bootstrap.min.css but they are in different folders, I have one for the editor and other for my web page. 
My code look like this.

```
<%@page import="unimb.praktikum.Baza"%>
<%@page import="java.util.ArrayList"%>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%> 

     <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <head>

        <!-- editor -->

        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <link href="editor/lib/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
            type="text/css" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="editor/lib/css/prettify.css" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="editor/src/bootstrap-wysihtml5.css" />


        <!-- web page -->

        <title>Generator izpitov</title>

        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

        <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
        <link
            href="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.0/css/bootstrap-toggle.min.css"
            rel="stylesheet">

        <!--web Bootstrap -->
        <style>
        body {
            padding-top: 50px;

        </head>

        <!-- ect... -->

        <body>

                            <!-- editor -->

                            <div class="col-md-5">

                                <textarea id="koda" class="textarea"
                                    style="width: 100%; height: 300px;"></textarea>
                            </div>

                        </div>

                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>

        </body>
```

Comment: Are you running the code in eclipse internal web browser?

Comment: yes..and i copied link and run it in chrome and it is the same..it destroys my dropdowns in web page and theme..i tried everything but always the same..but editor works fine..